# Dynamic IL method causes "Operation could destabilize the runtime"

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, il, dynamicmethod

> System.Security.VerificationException:
>   Operation could destabilize the
>   runtime.
>          at Connance.CommunicatorApi.ReportApiClient.AcknowledgeRecallsAsyncDynamicHandler(Object
>   , AcknowledgeRecallsCompletedEventArgs
>   )

That's the error I'm getting. What I'm trying to do (background) is create a global event handler for a class of methods. I'm working with a Static Proxy in WCF and I need to create a layer which tracks all the calls and returns to all of the WCF web methods. Unfortunately, WCF strongly types the "Completed" events' EventArgs, making it nearly impossible.

I decided to try something. If an event is `EventHandler<SomeSpecificEventArgs>`, I can still register a method of signature `void Method(object, object)` to handle the event. Great. So I set off to create a `DynamicMethod` which would call my **global** handler, and register it to each event.

I tried two ways:

> 1) DynamicMethod is of type void
>   (object, object)
>
> 2) of type void (object,
>   SomeSpecificEventArgs)  -- I use a
>   generic method for this to get the
>   type.

Only, when I try to invoke the method, either manually or for the event, I get the above exception.

Here's my code:

```
    // The handler for all callbacks.
// in the example it does nothing.
public void Handler(object sender, object e)
{
    dynamic evtArgs = e;
    object userState = evtArgs.UserState;
}

private string GetIdentifier(Delegate d)
{
    return string.Concat(d.Method.DeclaringType, '.', d.Method.Name);
}

// Method to register an event handler
public void Register<T> (Delegate o) where T : EventArgs
{
    // get some info
    /* snip. code to get method name, and calculate name of event */

    var eventInst = ownerType.GetEvent(eventName);

    // The following works, for example:
    // someObj.MethodCompleted += Handler;
    // even though MethodCompleted is an event of type EventHandler<SomeSpecialEventArgs>

    // get the actual type of handler
    var handlerType = eventInst.EventHandlerType;
    EventHandler evtHandler = new EventHandler(Handler);    

    DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod(
        GetIdentifier(o) + "DynamicHandler", // set the name
        typeof(void),                        // return void
        new[] { typeof(object), typeof(T) });// params object and type of event args

    ILGenerator gen = dm.GetILGenerator();

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // load first arg to stack for calling
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); // load second arg to stack for calling

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, evtHandler.Method); // call method

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // return

    // this is the final delegate
    var superdlg = dm.CreateDelegate(handlerType);

    // the problem beings here:
    // when the event is raised and the delegate is invoked
    // of if I dynamicInvoke it, I get the error
    eventInst.AddEventHandler(ownerInst, superdlg);
}
```

edit:
I see. It turns out I have another issue. I'm working in Silverlight. I managed to reproduce my scenario in a separate project and I got it working by using the overload of `DynamicMethod` which allows you to set an owner. I then specify

`DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("TestMethod2", typeof(void), new[] { typeof(MyClass), typeof(string), typeof(string) }, typeof(MyClass));`,

and use `ldarg.0`, `ldarg.1`, and `ldarg.2`. But this is a security critical constructor and won't run on silverlight. I'm just not sure how I need to set it up then. Do I make the `Handler` public static and load args 0-1? I end up getting an error like this:

> Attempt by method
>   'DynamicClass.TestMethod2(System.String,
>   System.String)' to access method
>   'dynamicass.MyClass.Handler(System.String,
>   System.String)' failed."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I came up was with this.

Make the `Handler` method an instance method, and add another argument type for the `DynamicMethod` constructor of the type of the class that owns it (for the implicit `this` argument).

then you do `dm.CreateDelegate(_args_, this)`

Answer (score 4):

Method arguments are zero indexed - use `ldarg.0` and `ldarg.1` instead of `ldarg.1` and `ldarg.2`

Theres also a problem with calling the event handler method - you're not specifying the `this` pointer for the method (`Delegate.Target`). You need to provide a `this` pointer, which may or may not be static depending on what is registered.

This also doesn't take care of multicast delegates - this would only call one of the handlers registered on the event. What you need to do is produce a method something like this:

```
.method public static CallEventHandler(EventHandlerType ev, object sender, EventArgsType e) {
    ldarg.0   // the Invoke 'this' pointer
    ldarg.1
    ldarg.2
    callvirt instance void EventHandlerType::Invoke(object, EventArgsType)
    ret
}
```

This uses the event's `Invoke` method, which deals with calling all the registered handlers for you.

Comment: I have experimented with using 0 and 1, but it looks like the DynamicMethod generates a static method, so it only takes the two explicit parameters instead of 3. Also, the event is being invoked in the normal way. There's code somewhere (not mine), which has a strongly typed reference to each event and raises it. I'm just trying to slip in my generic handler to track the state of these calls.

Comment: If the method is static, then the explicit parameters start at argument index 0. If the method is instance, then the 'this' pointer is argument 0 and explicit parameters start at index 1. The dynamic method is static, so you need to use `ldarg.0` and `ldarg.1`

Comment: I edited my question. It turns out I have an additional problem because I'm working in SL. I did manage to get it working in a regular app by using a Security critical constructor of DynamicMethod which binds it to an instance of the class I'm calling from (the constructor that sets owner). I then passed 3 args to it (first one being the implicit `this`)